# Some Debian packages, specifically Crossover, not installing on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, gdebi

Currently, I'm trying to install Crossover on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.10. However, the Debian package won't seem to install. This is not the only package that won't install. Off the top of my head I can't recall the other specific packages, but sometimes other Debian packages I've attempted to install fail with similar results. So, for this question I'll stick to Crossover specifically, because that's the one I'm trying to install at the moment.

I've tried various methods to install, but all have failed:

- I just opened it with Ubuntu Software Center and pressed the install button. The progress bar quickly goes from 0% to 100% then instead of actually being installed, or even giving me an error, the install button just appears again and the package is not installed.
- I tried installing from the command line using dpkg. I ran the following command: `sudo dpkg -i crossover.deb`.

### Output from dpkg

```
Selecting previously unselected package crossover:i386.
(Reading database ... 190815 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack crossover_18.5.0-1.deb ...
Unpacking crossover:i386 (18.5.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of crossover:i386:
crossover:i386 depends on libxi6.
crossover:i386 depends on libfreetype6.
crossover:i386 depends on libpng12-0 | libpng16-16.
crossover:i386 depends on libnss-mdns | lib32nss-mdns:amd64; however:
Package lib32nss-mdns is not installed.
crossover:i386 depends on libcups2; however:
crossover:i386 depends on liblcms2-2; however:
crossover:i386 depends on libglu1-mesa; however:
crossover:i386 depends on libxcursor1; however:
crossover:i386 depends on libxrandr2; however:

dpkg: error processing package crossover:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
crossover:i386
```

- I've also tried using gdebi from the command line by running the following command: `sudo gdebi crossover.deb`.

### Output from gdebi

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable 
Cannot install 'libcups2:i386'
```

- For grins I also tried opening it from the gdebi GUI. When I open the package gdebi states `Error: cannot install 'libcups2:i386'` under status, and the install package button is greyed out.

It seems to me there is an issue with dependencies. Judging by the gdebi results, I'm thinking the problem is with 'libcups2:i386'. But, I can't just keep chasing dependencies and trying to install them from the bottom up. So, I'm at a loss for what could be keeping the Crossover Debian package, and various other packages, from installing. What is the issue, and can it be resolved?